# Trying to install svn through pecl on rhel box, but unable to compile it

Tags: rhel

I am trying to install svn through pecl ($ pecl install svn) on rhel box.

But unable to compile it. I am giving the command ($ make) and getting the below output... Pleas help on this.

```
[root@ip-10-0-134-244 svn-1.0.3]# make
/bin/sh /root/svn-1.0.3/libtool --mode=link cc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/svn-1.0.3/include -I/root/svn-1.0.3/main -I/root/svn-1.0.3 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -o svn.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /root/svn-1.0.3/modules  svn.lo -lsvn_client-1 -lsvn_fs-1 -lsvn_repos-1 -lsvn_subr-1 -lapr-1
libtool: link: cc -shared  .libs/svn.o   -lsvn_client-1 -lsvn_fs-1 -lsvn_repos-1 -lsvn_subr-1 /usr/lib64/libapr-1.so -lpthread    -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,svn.so -o .libs/svn.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsvn_client-1
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [svn.la] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar error, and my solution involved installation via RPM package.

Since you did not mention PHP or RHEL version, I am not able to provide a deep link to an rpm that may help you, but I can provide something close.

- [Centos6pkgs](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/remi-x86_64/)
- [RPM resource for older php and fedora24](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=php-pecl-svn&submit=Search%20...)